# Java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:    
/home/stud/userx/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5_java/lib/ux64/liblpsolve55j.so: liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But in the folder is:

```
liblpsolve55j.so
liblpsolve55.so
```

Why does java not find it?

It is right there!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `java.library.path` property to the directory where the .so you need are located when launching the application, otherwise you'll get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, e.g.:

```
java -Djava.library.path=<path_to_.so> <main_class>
```

Comment: It says it looked for /home/stud/userx/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5_java/lib/ux64/liblpsolve55j.so and this file in this path exists, so the correct path is set i checked

Comment: Is `liblpsolve55.so` a real file or a symbolic link? Maybe the link is broken.

Comment: No it is a real file. I copied it there.

Comment: Do the directories along that path have the x modifier for the user that launched the application? (It's needed to list the content of the directory and find the files)

Comment: yes otherwise i couldn't view it myself, but i checked that also.